# Print nested PHP array as $var['key']['key']['key'] = value;

Tags: php, arrays, nested

Need to write (using fwrite()) some settings into php file in format:

```
$var['key']['key']['key'] = false; // bool
$var['key']['key'] = 'string'; // string
$var['key'] = 1; // numeric
```

Have nested php array for this

The code will override some values, defined above in the file, Var_export() useless in my case.

Any nice solution?

Comment: `$string = var_export($var, true)` doesn't work?

Comment: Why is `var_export` useless? Can you describe what you want to do some more?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what output you're trying to achieve please? Maybe provide some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [answered this question in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716409/get-perl-to-print-full-key-path-to-values-datadumper-wont/7718644#7718644) before — I guess I could just port the essentials of the answer to PHP:

```php
function dump_array_recursive ( $prefix, $var ) {
    if ( is_array( $var ) && !empty( $var ) ) {
        foreach ($var as $key => $val) {
            $prefix_key = $prefix . "[" . var_export( $key, true ) . "]";
            dump_array_recursive( $prefix_key, $val );
        }
    } else {
        echo "$prefix = " . var_export( $var, true ) . ";\n";
    }
}

// example call:
dump_array_recursive( '$foo', $foo );
```

This is a little bit simpler than the Perl version, since PHP has only one array type and no scalar references to worry about.  I also decided not to try collecting the output, but simply used `echo`; you can replace it with `fwrite()` if you want, or just use output buffering to catch the result in a string.

Ps. Note that, while the output of this function usually contains one line for each value, this is not guaranteed: the output of `var_export()` might contain newlines, which will be passed to the output.  Two cases which I've found to trigger such behavior include array keys with newlines in them and empty arrays, which for some reason are exported as `"array (\n)"`  instead of just `"array()"`.

Comment: Ilmari Karonen: greate, this is what i looking for!';

Comment: Only one weird thing: it adds `';` on the end. I tried to remove this by using rtrim() function but it does not work

Comment: There's _supposed_ to be a `';` at the end of each string assignment — that's what terminates the string and the statement.  Are you saying that there are somehow more `';`s than there should be?  If so, can you show me the input that causes that?

Comment: An example `$var['config']['galleryNoThumbs'] = 'true'; $var['config']['firstMod'] = 'spin'; $var['config']['zoomSlider'] = 'true'; $var['config']['spinEffect']['enabled'] = 'false;';`

Comment: Well, this is just a wild guess, but perhaps the value of `$var['config']['spinEffect']['enabled']` is indeed `'false;'`?

Comment: My bad, I overlooked that semicolon in the source. Sorry and thanks again for your help!

Comment: "just use output buffering to catch the result in a string" Could you provide an example how to do that? Should I use ob_get_clean() and ob_start()

Comment: Yes, exactly: `ob_start(); dump_array_recursive('$foo', $foo); $output = ob_get_clean();`